# Facebook Graph API Long-Lived Token

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-graph-api

I am working with Facebook Graph API and I have followed the instruction on the official documentation page to obtain a Long-Lived Token using a previously extracted access token by running the below code

```js
//Get long-lived access token
var longLiveToken = "https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/oauth/" +
  req.authInfo + "?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=" + process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID +
  "&client_secret=" + process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET + "&fb_exchange_token=" + req.authInfo +
  "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4000/";

https.get(longLiveToken, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers:', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    console.log(d);
  });

}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});
```

However I am getting the below error message

```
'www-authenticate': 'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "client_secret should not be passed to /oauth
```

My query is in line with the official documentation, not sure why I am getting this error message or how to go about resolving it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what is wrong with the code, I passed in wrong params. Below is the correct query

```js
var longLiveToken = "https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/oauth/" +
  "access_token" + "?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=" + process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID +
  "&client_secret=" + process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET + "&fb_exchange_token=" + req.authInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not provide `client_secret` value. Try to not provide `client` parameters. Maybe you're providing wrong `uri`, or not passing required parameters. It works if you would take a look again.

Comment: When i remove the client_secret, i get the error message `OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "Unknown OAuth 2.0 method]`. Not sure what you mean by wrong URI, are there any requirement the URI must satisfy apart from being registered on the App settings?

Comment: try passing params, what required